# best practices to use css and image with php routing

Tags: php, routes

For my new project I use PHP routing as a basis for the first time. The routing works fine so far, but I can't load css and img files from views/home.php. Can it be because it is configured so that only the public folder is accessible from the outside? If so, what is the best way to solve the problem. Do I just move the css and img files to the public folder? Wouldn't this be a security risk?

> - public/
>
>   - index.php
> - views/
>
>   - css/
>
>     - home.css
>   - img/
>
>     - logo.png
>   - home.php

Comment: Your CSS, images, js files, and so on, should be in the **public** folder.  These are files that are used on the frontend part of your application, and hence are required to be public.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. I will implement it like you sad